# htaccess rewrite incorrectly appending URL with mod_wsgi config file path

Tags: regex, django, apache, .htaccess, mod-wsgi

I'm currently in the process of migrating domains [old_domain] -> [new_domain].

The problem arose when I came to the htaccess rules and the config file in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:

**httpd.conf**

```
AllowOverride All
```

Initially I could not find where to put the above to allow .htaccess rewrite rules to work and I'm still concerned that I may be incorrectly allowing it for all.

I've tried putting it in something like but to no effect:

```
<Directory "/path/to/django/project/">
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Once I did get the .htaccess file rewrites working (using the following) the URLs started returning something odd.

**.htaccess in django project directory**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^old_domain.com/$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://new_domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

**URL sent**

```
http://old_domain.com/news/
```

**URL received**

```
http://new_domain.com/apache/production.wsgi/news/
```

Nearly there... but can anyone suggest why this might be happening? 
I don't really want to be stripping out the /apache/production.wsgi/ on the new_domain side (unless this is expected?)

Thanks in advance.

Edit: One quick fix included using django's HttpResponsePermanentRedirect. Is this bad practice?

Comment: Using HttpResponsePermanentRedirect means that your django app will be hit for each redirect. Best practice would be to minimise the systems touched before a redirect occurred. Django is one level deeper in the stack and so is extra overhead in returning the redirect response. Obviously, if you are serving minimal traffic though, the overhead is barely worth considering...

Comment: Edit your question and provide the mod_wsgi configuration as to how you are mounting your WSGI application. Are you using WSGIScriptAlias or Alias/AddHandler. Also see notes about rewrites in http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationGuidelines#The_Apache_Alias_Directive

Comment: The django redirects are on the old server, which is no longer used so an extra hit isn't too much of an issue. Will paste in the WSGI config when I can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use the rewrite directive within your django folder then you need to enable overides. Otherwise they will be ignored:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#allowoverride

Hopefully this does the trick for the rewrite:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^newdomain\.com 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

**Be sure to delimit the periods in the domain of you RewriteCond. In regex, . means "match all"**

Comment: Thanks roja. I'll try this out. I did forget to delimit the period.